# The type conflicts with imported namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, reference

What causing this error. I have 2 different page(.aspx) in one website. For the first page, i use `using Facebook` and doesn't have any error in this first page.

But for another new .aspx page. i using the `using Facebook` for reference but getting this error:

```
The type 'Facebook' in 'C:\Users\Documents\VS2010\Websites\Test\FacebookIntegration.aspx' conflicts with the imported namespace 'Facebook' in 'C:\Users\Documents\VS2010\Websites\Test\Bin\Facebook.dll. Using the type defined in 'C:\Users\Documents\VS2010\Websites\Test\FacebookIntegration.aspx'.
```

can someone please tell me why this is happen? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a class named `Facebook`, and a namespace called `Facebook`? If so, that's a problem. You should rename your class to something else, preferably something more descriptive. If you end up with two third party products, rename both of them [using an alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

I'm guessing you have a page called FacebookIntegration.aspx, but maybe you originally called it Facebook.aspx and so the class name ended up being `Facebook` and you just need to rename it, probably make it match the file name.

Comment: i want to hit up your answer, but my reputation is not enough to do that. it needs 15 point of reputation, mine is only 13. btw, thanks for you help